# Twitter Sharing

Tags: android, twitter

I need to post tweets not only with text but also with images.

I already tried `socialauth` library, which doesn't support images in tweets.

What is best way to implement twitter sharing from my Android application?

Answer (score 0):

Should work fine with scribe, haven't tested this sample in a while and I know twitter shut off some of its older APIs but I think the example still works fine.

Once you get your auth token you'll still do an OAuthRequest like my example, but the verb will be POST and you'll need to attach a body.  You'll use this API instead of verify_credentials https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/update_with_media

http://schwiz.net/blog/2011/using-scribe-with-android/